# Elixir characters Range

Tags: range, elixir

I play with **Range** in `Elixir`.

It works fine:

```
>1..10 |> Enum.map fn(x) -> x |> IO.puts end
>1
>..
>10
>[:ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok]
```

But here have error:

```
>'a'..'z' |> Enum.map fn(x) -> x |> IO.puts end
 ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Range.Iterator not implemented for 'a'
 /Users/elix_lang/lib/elixir/lib/range.ex:7: Range.Iterator.impl_for!/1
```

*I come from `Ruby` familiar with `Erlang`*

I want to understand what's the problem?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the 1st one, I think Enum.each can be used, if you just want to iterate through the range.

```
iex(1)> 1..10 |> Enum.each fn(x) -> IO.puts(x) end
iex(2)> 1..10 |> Enum.each &IO.puts(&1)
1
2
...
:ok
```

Regarding the 2nd one, one option might be like the following (though there may be a better way).

```
iex(3)> ?a..?z |> Enum.each &IO.puts(String.from_char_list!([&1]))
a
b
...
:ok

iex(4)> ?a..?z |> Enum.map(&String.from_char_list!([&1])) |> IO.puts
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
:ok
```

[2.3 Strings (binaries) and char lists (lists)] in the following covers some of the char list (?a, etc.)
   http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about the `?a` syntax.  That's handy.

Answer (score 13):

The provided answer no longer works in elixir 1.4.1 because String.from_char_list/1 was deprecated. You can now generate a list of characters like this:

```
?a..?z
|> Enum.to_list
|> List.to_string
```

Comment: As `?a` is 97 and `?z` is 122 this code just creates range `97..122` and later via `to_list` list of integers, and list of integers is on beam platform observed as list of characters.
One can then use pattern matching on that list or traverse it via recursion. Real candy. :)

Answer (score 6):

I quite like using the following syntax to generate a list of characters due to its clarity on *specifically* wanting the UTF-8 binary representation of the character returned, rather than its codepoint:

```
iex(1)> Enum.map(?a..?z, fn(x) -> <<x :: utf8>> end)
["a", "b", "c", ..., "z"]
```

Or, its `for` comprehension syntax:

```
iex(1)> for x <- ?a..?z, do: <<x :: utf8>>
["a", "b", "c", ..., "z"]
```

So, in your specific case:

```
iex(1)> Enum.map(?a..?z, fn(x) -> <<x :: utf8>> |> IO.puts() end)
a
b
c
# ...
z
[:ok, :ok, :ok, ..., :ok]
```

Comment: Nice, this is so clean, thanks!